# How to query latest records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've tried to to use similar asks but still not able to get my desired result. Here is three sample records.

```
create table #temps
(
    airport varchar(10),
    country varchar(10),
    plane varchar(10),
    id int,
    flight_date datetime
)

insert into #temps 
values ('IAD', 'USA', 'a777', '195', '  7/26/2022 11:39:00 AM')

insert into #temps 
values ('IAD', 'USA', 'a777', '195', '  8/12/2022 9:51:00 AM')

insert into #temps 
values ('BOS', 'USA', 'a777', '195', '  8/12/2022 9:51:00 AM')
```

I tried to retrieve the latest record which is from BOS airport (discard the impossible of the same flight dates occurred from different airports)

1. I used the `ROW_NUMBER` such as below and and wanted to return the max rank = 3.

   ```
    SELECT DISTINCT
        a.airport, a.country, a.flight_date, a.plane, id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY flight_date ASC) AS Ct
    FROM
        #temps a
   ```
2. I also tried the max such as

   ```
    SELECT A.airport, A.id, A.flight_date, A.country
    FROM #temps A
    INNER JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(flight_date) as MAX_FLIGHT_DATE 
                FROM #temps 
                GROUP BY id) B ON (A.flight_date = B.MAX_FLIGHT_DATE)
   ```

Is there a better technique that can return the record from BOS airport?

Thanks!
joe

Comment: "Better" how?  If these queries don't give you what you want, how are they deficient?

Comment: With two rows in your data with identical dates, how do you know BOS is the latest?

Comment: If you want the latest, why you order ASC?  Use Row_Number but dont filter by ct=3 but ct=1 then.

Comment: there's a flow in your table and it's id same for all records

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I have a table with 500k records. Can I still use ct =1?

Comment: @HungCaptain: no matter if you have 1 or 1 billion records, ofc you can use the same logic. Just use the right ordering DESC: `WITH cte as(SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY flight_date DESC) ct FROM #temps t) SELECT t.* FROM CTE t WHERE ct=1`

Comment: @TimSchmelter, Thanks for your prompt response. Much appreciate it. joe.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ORDER by.

```sql
SELECT TOP(3) airport,
              country,
              plane,
              id,
              flight_date
FROM #temps
ORDER BY flight_date DESC;
```

Comment: @tomtom, I was actually looking for the latest record. Top (3) returns all three sample records. Thanks for assisting. joe